# Calculating a value to return using recursion

Tags: recursion

In this recursive method, I am trying to calculate a number using the initial call `mystery5(-23, -48)`. After going through my first series of if statements, I get to the numbers `23` and `48`. Once I get to the else branch of the decision statements, what precedence does the method call have in the equation? Also, does a negative sign in front of the `mystery5` method call in the first two if statements indicate that there will be a positive `x` value if `-23` is inserted into the method call (Ex: `-mystery5(-23, -48)`)?

```
public int mystery5(int x, int y){
  if (x < 0) {
    return -mystery5(-x, y);
  } else if (y < 0) {
    return -mystery5(x, -y);
  } else if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return 100 * mystery5(x / 10, y / 10) + 10 * (x % 10) + y % 10;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it looks to me that `mystery5(1, 0)` returns 1. Assuming that is correct, then the call `mystery5(-1, 0)` would hit that first statement and it would see that `x = -1)` which is less than zero. This does `return -mystery5(-x,y)`, so when the values for `x` and `y` are put in, this is equivalent to `return -mystery5(1,0)`. The `-` in front of `mystery5` flips the sign on the result of the `mystery5` function when called. So when `mystery5(1,0)` returns a `1`, that gets negated to `-1`. And that is the final return value of `mystery5(-1,0)`.